# php script for using the on duplicate key update

Tags: php

am having a student table thata holds records of students. Am having a problem with the on duplicate update key function. With the way my system work, I randomly assign unique numbers 2 student after they save q record..

My query luk likes this

$length=(10000000,999999999);
$random=substr(uniqid,0,$length);
This query creates an alphanumeric unique key 4 me which works perfectly. .

My save query is dis

$save="insert into student (REG_NUMBER,username,surname)
VALUES('$random','username', '$surname')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
username='$username' ";
$result=mysql_query($save) or die(mysql_error());

The save part of the query works perfectly,
But it doesn't update the existing record,
Rather the it creates a new random id without updating 
The old record. Pls hw do I go about it..need help becos am new 2 php

Comment: What is the primary key of your table? This will be checked for duplicates.

Comment: The primary key is the $_session(random).once the record is saved,a unique number is given to the user.it is automatically assigned and its is not auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reg_number has to be a unique, primary key - so make sure it is.

Secondly, you are using $random as reg_number, can you guarantee it isn't a duplicate?

Thirdly, make sure that you don't have an AUTOIncrement property set on your reg_number column

Comment: Yes sir.it isn't a duplicate..the $_session(random) assigns the unique number into the database where the the reg_number holds the value.and it is not auto-incremented from the database. The number is being assigned frm the php script before being save into the database

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will only take effect if the key is the same. Giving a random unique key will create a new one until there is a collision.

Comment: Okay thanks boss..so can you please suggest a way I can assign unique keys to the user without creating a new random key..pls I really need your help

Comment: I think you are missing a lot of knowledge about databases here, best to read the manual or ask a different question on here

Answer (score 0):

The effects are not identical for an InnoDB table where primary_key/unique_key is an auto-increment column. With an auto-increment column, an INSERT statement increases the auto-increment value but UPDATE does not

check your engine as well as autoincrement in PK

Comment: The primary key is not auto incremented. The primary key in my query is the $_session(random) where its uniquely assigns a random number to each user after their record have been saved..